# Sound not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, 17.10

The computer stopped playing sound from its speakers and also when I use headphones. When I change the volume it shows the output device as the HDMI/Displayport, which doesn't make sense. I have nothing connected to the HDMI port. In sound settings, no input and output devices are shown. Please help. 
The picture link for what it looks like on my computer is here.

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

1. Down load "pulse audio volume control", package name: pavucontrol;
2. Go to the Configuration Tab
3. Specify the HDMI port as Off

Comment: It somehow started working now. It didn't let me access pavucontrol as well though. But thanks for the input.